# How to select just highlighted strings

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I double-click on a keyword `img` on line 37:

[image]

ST highlights matching strings and I would like to select all highlighted instances. However pressing "Alt+F3" selects also other strings that weren't part of highlighted matches:

[image]

Is there a shortcut to select just highlighted matches from first screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't select the word first, just hit `alt+f3`.